# Using webdriver, I am able to run successfully for the first user & for next user it is failing at if condition. If condition is not working properly

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

If condition is not working properly. I have some set of user id to login to my application, using webdriver, I am able to run successfully for the first user & for next user it is failing at if condition. Please find the code below and it has to check the more if conditions to run successfully.

```
for (int i = 1; i < sh.getRows(); i++)
{           
  while(iter.hasNext())
  {
   System.out.println("Main Window ID :"+iter.next());
  }
 driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_UserName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_UserName")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(0,   
  i).getContents());
    driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_Password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_Password")).sendKeys(sh.getCell(1, 
  i).getContents());
    driver.findElement(By.id("lgnLogin_LoginButton")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000L);

    if(driver.findElements(By.linkText("Logout")) != null)
        {

  driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_Header_Lbtn_Logout")).click();
            msg ="Valid User Login";
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
else
    if(driver.getTitle().contains("700Dealers Inc."))
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='lgnLogin']/tbody
  /tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td")).getText();
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
        else
        if(driver.getTitle().contains("Security Question And Answers"))
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='Table_01']/tbody
 /tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/span/span[1]")).getText();
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
        else
        if(driver.getTitle().contains("700 credit Change Password"))
        {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='panelscreen']/table
 /tbody/tr/th/span")).getText();
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
```

Please help me out in this issue. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does this iter.hasNext() contains?

Comment: What *exact line* does it fail?

Comment: Which if condition is failing and what is the error?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. And sorry for delay in reply. iter.hasNext() is used for handling the modalpopup window. It fails at "if(driver.findElements(By.linkText("Logout")) != null)" line. Error message displayed is       "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == ctl00_Header_Lbtn_Logout (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

Comment: The exception says that element with id = "ctl00_Header_Lbtn_Logout" is NOT found.

Comment: Yes, when  id = "ctl00_Header_Lbtn_Logout" is NOT found, it should execute the Else statements of the script, but it is not doing. It is giving error at this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(5000L);` is probably the root of your problems.

So, you may want to replace that :

```java
Thread.sleep(5000L);
if(driver.findElements(By.linkText("Logout")) != null)
```

with an explicit wait :

```java
try {
  WebElement logout = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5))
    .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
       @Override
       public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
        return d.findElement(By.linkText("Logout"));
     }});

  //Logout found, do stuff
} catch(TimeoutException e) {

  //No logout element, do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried with the above code, but is not working. it is giving the same error again.

Comment: @thotaumamaheshwar, (1) Sometimes I wish that `Thread.sleep()` would be just unavailable, so people would start using their brains a tiny bit more and use `.until()` element appears. (2) @n1r3, the problem here is that link with "Logout" is already there (not `null`), however the `ctl00_Header_Lbtn_Logout` is not there. Thota, can you post the HTML with those two items?

Comment: @n1r3 - I have made some small changes in your code and it worked for me. Your reply help me so much, as I am new to webdriver & I am comfortable in Selenium RC but my client want me to convert the scripts to Webdriver and i have immense pressure to complete the task by today. I was working hole night to complete my tasks along with this issue. Thanks alot for your reply.